# Rewriting jQuery fadeIn into Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I am currently using jQuery inside a Javascript function. For practice purposes I am trying to use vanilla Javascript throughout my entire project. However I cannot figure out how to rewrite the jQuery in regular Javascript.

What I currently understand what the jQuery line in my code does is that the style of `text` is set to `display: none`. Afterwards the `appendTo` sets the `innerHTML` of the class `.square-text`. Then `fadeIn` is used which I cannot place at all... I always thought that animation between `display` states is impossible?

Current JS code:

```
function transitionText(text){
  squareText.innerHTML = ""
  $(text).hide().appendTo(".square-text").fadeIn(800);
}
```

Comment: To make this work in plain JS you'd need to write your own animation routines, which is a lot of work for a simple fadeIn effect. It would be *much* easier (and perform better) to use CSS for the fade animation and just trigger it from JS by adding a class to the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/L9j68n2k)

You can use [css transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) for fading in or out. Basically something like:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", doFade);

function doFade() {
  const fadeInOut = document.querySelector("#fade");
  const faderClass = "fadeout";
  if (fadeInOut.classList.contains(faderClass)) {
    fadeInOut.classList.remove(faderClass);
  } else {
    fadeInOut.classList.add(faderClass);
  }
}
```

```css
#fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity linear 0.8s 0s;
}

#fade.fadeout {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity linear 0.8s 0s;
}
```

```html
<div id="fade">Something to fade in or out</div>

<p><button>FadeInOut</button></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! If I want to have multiple sentences on that same spot, I can also first change a `display: none` to `display: block` and than change it to `fade` correct? So first the text is actually in the block (without pushing away other text) and than the fade in starts?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @Pimmesz, maybe something like http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/L9j68n2k?